# discord.js delete message if it contains a space

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot delete a message if it contains a space, but it does not seem to work.

```js
oneword.on('message', message => {
    if (Attivo == true) {
        messaggio.push(message.content)
        console.log("il bot riceve un messaggio")
        if (message.content.includes(" ")) {
            message.delete(200)
        }
        return
    }
})
```

But whenever I try and do it (i enter the command ";start") it crashes and gives this error.

```
    /home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:501
        if (typeof options !== 'object') throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'options', 'object', true);
                                         ^
    
    TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
        at Message.delete (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:501:44)
        at Client.oneword.on.message (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/index.js:16:55)
        at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
        at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/broog/discord-bot-terzo/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

What's happening here and how do I fix this?

It's my first discord bot so I'm really unexperienced in discord.js (and even JavaScript)

(Yes I know this isn't all of the code but trust me it works if I leave that second if statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to delete the message with a timeout. Your code was working using Discord.js v11. At this time, the latest version is v12. You should use an option object:

```js
oneword.on ('message', message=>{
    if(Attivo == true){
    messaggio.push(message.content)                            
    console.log("il bot riceve un messaggio")
    if (message.content.includes(" ")) {message.delete({ timeout: 200 })}
    return
        }
    }
}
```